# Saving image file path in a member variable?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, filepath, image-gallery

I'm trying to create simple Contact app. Naturally there is `Contact` class with member variable `mCurrentPhotoPath`. An activity which is responsible for creating Contact, has an option to pick image from Gallery in the following way:

```
  final Intent pickImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  pickImage.setType("image/*")
  /*some code...*/
  galleryButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        startActivityForResult(pickImage, REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO);
    });

   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        photoTaken = true;

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Log.i("path", selectedImage.getPath()) //prints out: /document/image:292562
        mPhotoView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
```

I am able to display selected image in ImageView (`mPhotoView`).

However, when I try to set Intent in different way, I get full path, but I cannot recreate file from that path and I get `FileNotFoundException`.

```
final Intent pickImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            photoTaken = true;

             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

             if (selectedImage != null) {
                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                 if (cursor != null) {
                      cursor.moveToFirst();

                      int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                      String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                      Log.i.("TAG", picturePath); //I get, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Viber/IMG-bbd54c96cc971a1700f92205937014c8-V.jpg
                      mPhotoFile = new File(picturePath);
                      cursor.close();
                      updatePhotoView(); //This method recreates image based on exact file path and witdh & height of ImageView where the picture is going to be placed;
                 }
            }

         }
```

Here is `updatePhotoView()`

```
private void updatePhotoView(int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
        if (mPhotoFile == null || !mPhotoFile.exists()) {
            mPhotoView.setImageDrawable(null);

        } else {
            Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(mPhotoFile.getPath(),imageWidth, imageHeight); // imageWidth & imageHeight are member variables of actiivty...

            mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure this function works, because when I implemented option to take picture from camera (I created file with getExternalFilesDir(), and in any other activity when I passed string value of `mCurrentPhotoPath`, `getScaledBitmap()` managed to recreate image).

Here is `getScaledBitmap()`:

```
public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String path, int destWidth, int destHeight) {
        // Read in the dimensions of the image on disk
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        float srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        float srcHeight = options.outHeight;
        // Figure out how much to scale down by
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (srcHeight > destHeight || srcWidth > destWidth) {
            if (srcWidth > srcHeight) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round(srcHeight / destHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round(srcWidth / destWidth);
            }
        }
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        // Read in and create final bitmap
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of `updatePhotoView()' method?

Comment: Yes sir, I'll updated it in few moments.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Sir, I have edited my post :)

Comment: You should save data.getData().toString(), the content scheme,  so you can construct your uri back when needed. data.getData().getPath() is useless as you have seen.

Comment: Try using `picturePath` directly in your `getScaledBitmap()` method instead of  creating file and getting path `mPhotoFile = new File(picturePath);`.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi When I pass `picturePath` to getScaledBitmap(), I get: BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Viber/IMG-74de1b5454adae38a7413ea7745174e4-V.jpg (Permission denied)

Comment: @blackapps If I understand correctly, are you suggesting that instead of saving String in mCurrentContactPath, instead, to set Uri currentPhoto as member variable in Contact class? And when I need to set that image any where, I just call imageView.setImageURI(currentPhoto ); ? And by "..construct your uri back when needed" you are referring to Uri.parse(someStringUri) ?

Comment: `... saving String in mCurrentContactPath` What would that be? I never said such. Please reread my comment.

Comment: Yes Uri uri = Uri.parse( the content scheme string that i saved); Where the content scheme string that i saved is data. getData().toString(). Quite confusing that you introduce all kind of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone stumbles on similar problem. I solved my problem of getting images by using Glide library. Look it up, bunch of tutorials. I guess that this `load` function is doing heavy lifting in the background. Great thing! Here is how code looks like:

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageFilePath)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
                .override(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight())
                .into(imageView);
```